# How to insert data with foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the best ( I mean the fastest and simplest) way to inserting data with foreign key?

My models:

```
public class Package
{
    public Int PackId { get; set; }
    // some fields

    // list with other models! 
    public ICollection<Shipment> shipments { get; set; }
}

public class Shipment
{
    Int Id { get; set; }
    // some fields

    [ForeignKey]
    Int PackId { get; set; }
    Package package { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create a `Package` and some `Shipments` in one request (data comes via form). I do it in this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public void ControllerMethod(MyViewModel form)
{
    transaction
    {
        // empty list,method from 
        var pack_id = _packageRepository(some_fields_here, new List<Shipment>());

        // repo returns id
        var package = _packageRepository.GetSpecific(pack_id);

        var ls_shipments = new List<Shipment>();

        foreach(var x in form.ListOfShipments)
        {
            var ship = _shipRepository.Add(some_fields_here, pack_id, package);
            ls_shipments.Add(ship);
        }

        // replace empty list with list filled in foreach above
        package.shipments = ls_shipments; 

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // some actions here
    }
}
```

It looks quite odd, but I need create package and many shipments in one action. Moreover I adding new `Package` and then I getting it from database - is this the simplest way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use separate repository for master and detail tables. Map you view models fields to master and detail entities and call master Add method only it will keep track of children itself. If PackId is autonumber then you don't need to do any thing. if it is not assign primary key of pkgid to foreign key of shipment

```
var _Package = new Package();
// Assign fields of packages from viewmdoel to entity
foreach(var item in form.shipments)
{
var _Shipment = new Shipment();
//Assign shipment fields from your view models to shipment entity
_Package.shipments.Add(_Shipment)
}

using (var dbCtx = new yourDBEntities())
{
    //add package entity into  entitySet
    dbCtx.Package.Add(_Package);
    //Save whole entity graph to the database
    dbCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

or you call you repo method from package for add/Save

You can see a simple tutorial [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework4.3/add-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: Doesn't he need to add Shipments to table Shipment? Does EF core add them automatically to the table Shipment?
What is "yourDbEntities"? I have almost the same question.

Comment: Okay,it works for me. But list in MainModel is null.

Comment: that is a separate issue you may use helper for example https://github.com/saad749/BeginCollectionItemCore

Comment: What is yourDBEntities()? It's not new context, right? How to create new object and which class?

Comment: I don't know about your repository  just added that part for completeness.  i  think your repo should have a add method then you can ignore this and call _packageRepository.Add(_Package);